# png files failing to load when opening html file directly, but they load when opening from webstorm

Tags: javascript, html, webstorm, p5.js

I've been working on a game in javascript for my CS course. When I open the document by hitting run in Webstorm, it loads the game correctly, however when I just try opening the html file from Finder, the webpage opens but none of the png files I'm using for the sprites load. I opened Inspect Element in google chrome, and the javascript files loaded correctly but all the png files listed as canceled. This doesnt happen when the game is run from webstorm (when I run it from webstorm, all image files load properly).

When the game is opened directly from an html file (that's when I have the problem), chrome lists the path of the html document as the webaddress, although when opened from webstorm, it lists http://localhost:63342/CS%20Week%2010/CS105_Jessica.Davis_DogGame.html?_ijt=tmrr2fndgac82h07hlvt101gi4

How can I get around this issue so that when opening the html file from Finder it loads everything correctly? All image files are in the same directory as the html file.

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve]? Also, why is this an issue? You probably shouldn't be opening your html file that way anyway.

Comment: I need to be able to ensure that the TA grading my work will be able to open and play my game.

Comment: Are they not going to be running their own server to run your files? If not, then they should have instructions for how they want you to do things.

Answer (score 2):

Because of browsers security, loading files like this might not work from a url starting with `file://`

What webstorm is probably is making a local web server so that instead of saying `file://` you could say `http://`. if any website was able to load images from `file://` then any webpage you visit would have been able to search for any file on your computer and send it over the internet without your consent so browser often have these settings on. So you'd need a server. If you are working on your computer, you could make a local server just like webstorm and host your own files there. or host it on another service like github pages or codepen.

Now since all images are in the same directory, make sure that every time you call `loadImage` you use the images name and extension instead of saying `/User/user/whatever_other_directory_you_have_it_under/image.png`.

Once you did that you can make a local web server for the project. To make a local server, open Terminal (an application under utilities, you could spotlight search for it as well) and type `cd`, drag your project folder and drop it over terminal, and hit enter. Then type python -m SimpleHTTPServer and wait till it says something like `Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...`. Then taking the 0.0.0.0 and the 8000 you see in the example (yours may or may not be the same) go to your browser and type http://0.0.0.0:8000 (replacing the digits with whatever you got, not this link doesn't work until you do that)

Images should load alright. If you need to stop the server you can go back to terminal and hit `control+C`.

Note that when presenting your p5 sketch, no one else would be able to see the website on their computers if you make your local server. The local server is secluded to the device that is running it (although if their making their own local server and have your project files it should work just fine).

If you want the website hosted so that you could share a link with anybody in the world you could use codepen or github pages. If you go to codepen.io it should be self-explanatory although you'd have to upload your images to some image hosting site like tumblr or something and add the URL source of those images to codepen or you could put everything into github for even better results!

To use github pages you'd need to make a github account (preferably with your username being whatever you want your page to be named). Make a repository named `insert_username_here.github.io`. add your files to the repository (make sure to try to keep all sub directories and folder exactly as they are from your project folder). After a minute or two go to `http://insert_username_here.github.io` to admire your brand new hosted webpage!